# Google Maps Eventos

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I would like to know if there is any possibility of returning a global addListener and not as below:

> google.maps.event.addListener(map, "**click**", function(event) {

In the case without the CLICK option (in this case when clicking on the map, but something

> google.maps.event.addListener(map, function(event) {

And inside it make the CASES to check if it was CLICK, ZOOM or other, the reason for this is that I have 3 separate events 1 for CLICK, 1 for ZOOM_CHANGE and one for POSITION_CHANGE all of them update the map and add new information, however The 3 are executing the action and ending up getting 3 information on the map in some situations:

Situation 1: When I change the zoom it does the position and the zoom and this way it gets 2 information on the map.

The intention would be through the CASE is that I can use the Break from here and it does only one action, but I can not do a global addListener.

Thanks for the help of someone who knows how I can do it.

Comment: Questions must be in English on this site.

Comment: Sorry, 
I did not realize, I'll be editing.

Comment: Just setup a flag!